# struct.field returns another value, why?

Tags: c, struct

My goal is to create an `fisrt` of my custom `struct` type.
When run, prints out 24.
Can't understand why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct strktura {
    int number;
    char name;
} strktura;

strktura new_one(int number, char name){
    strktura a;
    a.number=number;
    a.name=name;
}

main()
{
        strktura first=new_one(2,"A");
        printf("%d\n",first.number);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to `return` from `new_one()`.

Related Reading: From chapter 6.9.1, paragraph 12, `C11` document,

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So, in your code, without a `return` from `new_one()` and by accessing the return value through `printf("%d\n",first.number);`, you're facing [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, worthy to mention, the correct syntax for `main()` is `int main()`, (and a matching `return 0` is a good practice.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a

```
return a;
```

in your new_one() function so that the structure gets returned from the function new_one()